# Converting epoch timestamp into a readable date

Tags: javascript, datetime, epoch, date-conversion

I'm retrieving a value which is supposed to be a epoch timestamp from a database and trying to convert it back to a date format to display it into a screen.

I can see that I'm retrieving the correct value i.e. 1644537600 which should represent  Friday, 11 February 2022 00:00:00.

When I do the following `var date = new Date(parseInt(timestamp));`  I get `Tue Jan 20 1970 01:48:57`

I tried to divide timestamp / 1000 or 1000000 but I get the same result.

It could be with date formatting but struggling to make it work.

Comment: JS Date is in milliseconds, you have to multiply your timestamp by 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That epoch is in seconds, you need to multiply it by 1000.

Comment: It works, thanks so much!